# Fluent Assertions how to Exclude parameters with generic object

Tags: unit-testing, testing, fluent-assertions

I have this generic method for a test class that I want to exclude some common parameters between few entities.

```
private static bool IsEquivalentTo(object request, object expectedRequest)
{
    request.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectedRequest, config => config.Excluding(c => c.SelectedMemberPath.EndsWith("Id"))
        .Excluding(c => c.SelectedMemberPath.EndsWith("Date"))
        .Excluding(c => c.SelectedMemberPath.EndsWith("Equipment"))
        .Excluding(c => c.SelectedMemberPath.EndsWith("Partners"))
        .Excluding(c => c.SelectedMemberPath.StartsWith("Warranty"))
    );
    return true;
}
```

Since the last versions, this `SelectedMemberPath` is deprecated. Did someone find a solution for generic objects with the latest version?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SelectedMemberPath` has been replaced by `Path` in [version 6.0](https://fluentassertions.com/releases/#600):

```cs
request.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectedRequest, config => config
    .Excluding(c => c.Path.EndsWith("Id"))
    .Excluding(c => c.Path.EndsWith("Date"))
    .Excluding(c => c.Path.EndsWith("Equipment"))
    .Excluding(c => c.Path.EndsWith("Partners"))
    .Excluding(c => c.Path.StartsWith("Warranty")));
```